# Can a Neo4j identifier start with an integer?

Tags: neo4j

```
MATCH (p:Product {id:'19134046594'})-[r]-> (o:Attributes {4g:'network'}) return o
```

I received this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Invalid input ':': expected an identifier character, whitespace or '}' (line 1, column 66 (offset: 65))
```

It's complaining about '4g'. Is '4g' an invalid property key identifier in neo4j? How to work around the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the backtick (`) character to quote property names that start with an otherwise illegal character.

For example, this would work:

```
CREATE (o:Attributes {`4g`: 'network'})
RETURN o;
```

And this also works:

```
MATCH (o:Attributes) WHERE o.`4g` = 'network'
RETURN o;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [naming rules section](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/naming/) of the documentation, names you use (which does include property keys):

> Must begin with an alphabetic letter.

and

> Can contain numbers, but not as the first character.

You can however start it off with an underscore, so `_4g:'network'` would work.

I'm guessing this is just for example purposes, but it does seem to me that it would be better the other way around: `network:'4g'`.